# Pass additional data to kendoui popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

i need know to how to pass additional data to a create popup in kendo grid control.
I need to pass an ID from a external controler, for example:

I have a kendo treeview, when i click on the create button from the grid, i need the ID of the selected node in the kendo treeview to use them in the popup create window. i cant display the treeview in the popup window, so i need use this way to finish the page.
im using mvc4 asp.net and the kendo ui controls.

How can i do this??

Comment: your requirement fulfill for this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/checkboxes.html

Comment: tkx im resolve this problem using JS